# Is it possible to auto-update a Wordpress loop if the contents of the loop have changed?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, meteor, websocket

What I'm wanting to be able to do is create a page that lists all the posts of a custom post type, and if someone creates a new post, anyone viewing the listing page will see the new post appear in real time.

I've done some research and it looks like what I'm wanting is a 'persistent client/server connection'? Something like with Meteor, or Ajax, or WebSockets? (I've read a bit about those technologies and I'm still a little fuzzy on if these do what I'm looking for)

My current solution is to blindly refresh the post listing page for visitors every 60 seconds, but it's not very realtime, and it causes increased bandwidth usage to reload the entire page every minute, even if there are no new changes to the wordpress custom posts database.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm happy to clarify anything that I may have been vague about.

Comment: Did you already start to create a project with Meteor? If so please post some code of it. If not you should try it out. It is all [set up in a few Minutes](https://www.meteor.com/install) and [well documented](https://guide.meteor.com/). There is also a [great community](https://forums.meteor.com/) that helps with questions that are too unspecific for SO.

Comment: No I haven't yet, I've been approaching it from an AJAX perspective. I'm still reloading incrementally, but at least I've been able to reload just a ajax content I need, and not the entire page.